# Deposit in AAVE v2 contract from HardHat

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, aave

I'm trying to deposit into AAVE v2 using hardhat.


My code is the following:

```js
const hre = require('hardhat')

...

const contractAddress = '0x7d2768de32b0b80b7a3454c06bdac94a69ddc7a9'
const contract = await hre.ethers.getContractAt(AABI, contractAddress)
contract.deposit()

...
```

But I get the error:

> contract.deposit is not a function hardhat-fork_1  | TypeError:
> contract.deposit is not a function

If I print the variable 'contract' I can see that something is retrieved by the blockchain but it does not contain the method.

Which is weird because I used the address [specified here](https://docs.aave.com/developers/v/2.0/deployed-contracts/deployed-contracts) (LendingPool 0x7d2768de32b0b80b7a3454c06bdac94a69ddc7a9) and the ABI for the LendingPool address [specified here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7d2768de32b0b80b7a3454c06bdac94a69ddc7a9#code).

I didn't put any file inside the hardhat contracts folder, should I?

My assumption is that since the contract is already on the chain I should be able to get it and use its methods.

Any idea on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the documentation, you should retrieve the LendingPool address from the LendingPoolAddressesProvider smart contract:
https://docs.aave.com/developers/v/2.0/the-core-protocol/addresses-provider

Here is an example in Solidity: https://github.com/pooltogether/aave-yield-source/blob/d8843c1dfb7327106d3b83af58fc6e4407fd949f/contracts/yield-source/ATokenYieldSource.sol#L300

It should be fairly similar in JavaScript.

Also, the deposit function requires 4 parameters, so it may be why if fails to call it in your example.
https://docs.aave.com/developers/v/2.0/the-core-protocol/lendingpool#deposit

Answer (score 0):

The error is that I used the ABI provided in [the etherscan page](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7d2768de32b0b80b7a3454c06bdac94a69ddc7a9#code) which was the ABI of the proxy and not the LendingPool one.
I had to use the ABI provided in the [AAVE doc](https://docs.aave.com/developers/v/2.0/the-core-protocol/lendingpool#abi) instead.